# How does JWT.io already know my public key?

Tags: jwt, rsa

My JSON Web Token (JWT):

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6InU0T2ZORlBId0VCb3NIanRyYXVPYlY4NExuWSIsImtpZCI6InU0T2ZORlBId0VCb3NIanRyYXVPYlY4NExuWSJ9.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.kwfGrWiQwqhJpZfryW9D1hHDC2AC6tUT16OXkmlIeyxTMqY0gdO0U3KClYczDzMs6kpXc5sQOBaTrBQgERnfKf1nqrHoDmHzaKmY20LKByMopH9uhcPF3lkDNW--dfruNHywF6DZ4cLtgSWcZOBs_BAwQqy1i5Hja7WNf5InyhyscXjUdntIz9rK599IzvD8MwkgYViMEXATNNh2CvEqRp-AZxVjCP_cI6h9Lx3j8__9xRIoWIwnv_rqHGcPpg6hJMfUJMtlLjJaBo0h0veCCZj-fUORidN7EPHNSw9IJF29-nGhw6rmkcD7F8q6WpK8dUfiYGk_QxOCRTw9gpkKKA
```

When I paste this token into `jwt.io`, it automatically fills in a public key and says the signature on the token has been verified. How does it know the public key?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From JWT Best Current Practices [(RFC 8725)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8725) :

> The means of determining the keys owned by an issuer is application-
> specific.  As one example, OpenID Connect issuer values
> are `https` URLs that reference a JSON metadata document that contains
> a `jwks_uri` value that is an `https` URL from which the issuer's keys
> are retrieved as a *JWK Set* ([RFC 7517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517)).  This same mechanism is used by
> `ietf-oauth-discovery`.  Other applications may use different
> means of binding keys to issuers.

The OpenID Connect (OIDC) provider metadata location is documented in [OIDC Discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) specification

> OpenID Providers supporting Discovery MUST make a JSON document
> available at the path formed by concatenating the string
> `/.well-known/openid-configuration` to the `Issuer`. The syntax and
> semantics of `.well-known` are defined in [RFC 5785](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5785) and apply
> to the `Issuer` value when it contains no path component.

The payload of your token is

```js
{
  "aud": "https://management.azure.com/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/",
  "iat": 1563406664,
  "nbf": 1563406664,
  "exp": 1563410564,
  "aio": "42FgYBBtfzSr7br/p4tqeqdl/2wNBgA=",
  "appid": "f1f6d55e-cf2c-422d-b186-848624db95e8",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/",
  "oid": "df9dff8d-bcb5-4b17-8cec-4be1a01f9212",
  "sub": "df9dff8d-bcb5-4b17-8cec-4be1a01f9212",
  "tid": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47",
  "uti": "hi01-8YRuEmLLcxM9L3zAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

The `Issuer` is represented by the `iss` claim. If you take the value of `iss`, append `/.well-known/openid-configuration` to it and pop the [resulting URL](https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/.well-known/openid-configuration) into your browser, you'll see the OIDC Provider metadata. One of the keys in this metadata document is `jwks_uri` which points to another document with a *JSON Web Key Set*. The latter is a set of *JSON Web Keys* (JWKs). A JWK is a JSON representation of a crypto key. To identify the desired JWK in the set, the claims `x5t` (SHA-1 thumbprint of a X.509 certificate) and/or `kid` (key id / alias / name) from the token in question are used.

`jwt.io` successfully cheats on the very first step of this whole sequence by pulling OIDC metadata based on `iss` claim. If the JWT was issued by a service that did not speak OpenID Connect and/or did not implement all of these related specifications, `jwt.io` wouldn't have found the key to validate the signature.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to implement something in C++ to validate certain JWT tokens and this helps.

Comment: The last line of the answer has the important info: "If the JWT was issued by a service that did not speak OpenID Connect and/or did not implement all of these related specifications (OIDC specs), jwt.io wouldn't have found the key to validate the signature."