# How do I know when to ask for refreshed JWT tokens served from an outside source (Signal Wire in this case)

Tags: python

To begin with, please understand that I have little formal training in Front Stack development.  I've had to learn a lot on the job, and our only experienced developer left about a year ago, so I very well might not know something I should.

My current cunumdrum is that I don't know how to check when a JWT token I have has expired, that I did not create. How would I know? Since I don't know the secret used to generate it. I could possibly just record when I made the request for the token(s), and how long I made the timeout, but I wonder if there will be a disconnect between when I made the request and time the token acttualy expires.

I ask, because I don't want to randomly call to refresh any of these tokens. Only when they expire.

If it helps, we are using Python 3.6 in the backend and making a request to Signal Wire for the tokens

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JWT token usually has three parts, each of them being base64-encoded. The payload part usually holds an expiration date as seconds since 1970-01-01.

This could be a token:

`eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTYiLCJ0eXAiOiAiSldUIn0.eyJleHAiOiAxNTM2MzYxNDExLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ICJBYmUgTGluY29sbiIsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ICJBYmVMaUBtaWNyb3NvZnQuY29tIn0.c2Rmc2FkZmFzZmRzYWZkYXNmZA`

Each of the parts (separated by a dot) can be base64-decoded (as https://jwt.io/ does):

1. Header - usually algorithm and token type, e.g.:

```
    {
      "alg": "HS256",
      "typ": "JWT"
    }
```

2. Payload - whatever content the token has, usually some information on the user ID and the expiration date of the token, e.g:

```
    {
      "exp": 1536361411,
      "username": "Abe Lincoln",
      "preferred_username": "AbeLi@microsoft.com"
    }
```

3. Signature: some binary value

A token usually even gives you enough information to retrieve the signing key. See the answer on [How does JWT.io already know my public key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085381/how-does-jwt-io-already-know-my-public-key/57085953) for more details or dig into the [OpenID Connect Discovery Protocol](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) for full understanding.