# I have created a JWT object with some data. Then I decode that same JWT object just to compare and see if the validation passes. But it does not

Tags: java, jwt

I have created a JWT object with some data. Then I decode that same JWT object just to compare and see if the validation passes. But it does not. Following is the code I have created. What could be the issue?

```
              SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;
              //Make a JWT Token String

              String jws = Jwts.builder().setSubject("adam")
               .setExpiration(new java.util.GregorianCalendar(2021, 
                                                        Calendar.NOVEMBER, 8).getTime())
               .setIssuer("someUser@mycompany.com")
               .claim("groups", new String[] { "user", "admin" })

                // HMAC using SHA-512  and 12345678 base64 encoded
                .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, "MTIzNDU2Nzg=").compact();

              System.out.println("JWTS String: "+ jws.toString());

              //=================================================
              //Decode the string back           
              Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
              String[] chunks = jws.split("\\.");
              String header = new String(decoder.decode(chunks[0]));
              String payload = new String(decoder.decode(chunks[1]));
              String signature = chunks[2];
             
              System.out.println("Header: " + header);
              System.out.println("PayLoad: " + payload);
              System.out.println("Signature: " + signature);

              String tokenWithoutSignature = chunks[0] + "." + chunks[1];
              SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new
                SecretKeySpec("MTIzNDU2Nzg=".getBytes(),signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());
              DefaultJwtSignatureValidator validator = new
                DefaultJwtSignatureValidator(signatureAlgorithm,secretKeySpec);

              if (validator.isValid(tokenWithoutSignature, signature)){
                    System.out.println("TOKEN IS VALID");
              }else{
                    System.out.println("TOKEN IS INVALID");
              }
```

Comment: does your token have an expiration?

Comment: What is the result of `GregorianCalendar(2021,  Calendar.NOVEMBER, 8).getTime()` ? Isn't it just the current time? If you set the expiration time like this, your token will always be expired.  Instead use something like current time + x minutes, and without setting a fixed date. Can you pls. add the actual token to the question?

Comment: I modified the expiration date by adding 10 minutes. But still the validation fails.   ```Long currentTime = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();```
```Date expirationDate = new Date( currentTime + 600000);```
```logger.info("currentTime: "+ currentTime);```
```String jws = Jwts.builder().setSubject("adam")
                              .setExpiration(expirationDate) ```

Comment: Please share your token, so we can see if the exp is s correct unix timestamp in seconds.

Comment: I ran the verifier in jwt.io/#encoded-jwt using the secure string eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZGFtIiwiZXhwIjoxNjM2NDAzOTYzLCJpc3MiOiJzb21lVXNlckBteWNvbXBhbnkuY29tIiwiZ3JvdXBzIjpbInVzZXIiLCJhZG1pbiJdfQ.lpy7bAGHrJ40t75Pr8CpdS4rVgDs9SvyXo3NKaXqEio created in the above code (String jws).  The verifire tool says Signarure Verified. I do not understand why the validator.isValid () brings me false. Here is the token contents. 
```{
  "alg": "HS256"
}```

{
  "sub": "adam",
  "exp": 1636403963,
  "iss": "someUser@mycompany.com",
  "groups": [
    "user",
    "admin"
  ]
}

Comment: Actually, the timestamp seem off. I printed the time stamp during program execution is it was 1636403963193, but the exp: 1636403963 in the token has dropped last 3 digits?????

Comment: The timestamp in the token is correct, as mentioned above it's a UNIX Timetamp in seconds since 1970/01/01 00:00 UTC. Your number is in milliseconds. Don't know how you got a verified signature, I could not verify the signature with the given secret that you show in your question. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862105/jwt-io-says-signature-verified-even-when-key-is-not-provided) how you can verify a signature on jwt.io (and avoid the most common error that lets you believe you verified, even when the secret is wrong)

Comment: I agree. I did that in the wrong order at jwt.io. But my biggest concern is why isValid() method return false in spite of hardcoding the right secret and feeding correct algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to base64 decode the secret first.

replace...

```
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("MTIzNDU2Nzg=".getBytes(),signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());
```

with

```
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(TextCodec.BASE64.decode("MTIzNDU2Nzg="), signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());
```

and it should work!