# Invalid signature when trying to verify JWT

Tags: java, jwt

I have a JWT with the secret key :

```
private final static Algorithm ALGORITHM = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret");


public String createToken(@NonNull String username) {

       
        Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z"))));
        Timestamp expTime = Timestamp.from(Instant.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z")).plusMinutes(10))); 

     

     try {
            String token = JWT.create()
                    .withIssuer("auth0")
                    .withClaim("username", username)
                    .withClaim("time", timestamp).withExpiresAt(expTime) 
                    .sign(ALGORITHM);
            return token;
```

and the verify method:

```
public DecodedJWT verifyToken(String token) {

        DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(token);

        try {
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT
                    .require(ALGORITHM)
                    .withIssuer("auth0")                    
                    .build();
            DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
            return jwt;


        } catch (JWTVerificationException exception) {
            System.out.println("token not verified");
        }
```

My problem is that the token returned from the method has an invaild signature as by https://jwt.io/ . Also the verify method is not working because of that.
I read some blogs in which they said that you have to encode your secret, so I tried it like this:

```
private final static   Algorithm ALGORITHM = Algorithm.HMAC256(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("secret".getBytes()));
```

but it didnt work the signature was also invalid. Has anyone an idea on how can I fix that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: regarding jwt.io: you probably did not provide the secret there, so jwt.io can't verify. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862105/jwt-io-says-signature-verified-even-when-key-is-not-provided/69862239#69862239) how to do it. And in your verify method I also don't see the secret anywhere. Generally for verification the verifying function needs to know the secret (or public key in case of asymmetric algorthms). And please also show the token here.

Comment: thx for the jwt.io tip but how do I pass my secret in the verify method?

Comment: did it work now on jwt.io? And can you please show your token here? What jwt library do you use?

Comment: on jwt.io it worked but my verify method didnt work here my token  : eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhdXRoMCIsInRpbWUiOjE2NDI2ODQ0NzAsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoidXNlcm5hbWUifQ.Gn4ZGjMYBfEqJwJ7cI8hcd1NLgkRp5e7LieezKsSvo0

Comment: and I am using the Java Jwt auth0 library

Comment: the token you have shown can't be verified with "secret".

Comment: what is the actual exception in `catch (JWTVerificationException exception)`? In your code you ignore it and just print a generic error.

Comment: com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.InvalidClaimException: The Claim 'username' value doesn't match the required one.

Comment: I fixed the username issue but now I got the exception:  com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.TokenExpiredException: The Token has expired on Thu Jan 20 14:44:07 CET 2022.

Comment: strange, actually your token doesn't have a proper expiration time. You use "time", but for expiration the correct claim name is "exp". Try setting "exp" instead of time and see if it works.