# Keeps on getting 401 from postman using JWT token

Tags: api, asp.net-core, http-status-code-401

I have created an API project using .NetCore 6.  I have followed the tutorials and I think I have not missed anything.  I run the program and it works fine not until I have implemented to only Authorize user has access to it.

So I have implement JWT Authentication.  I have verified the token in https://jwt.io/ and I got a signature Verified.  But when I tried to call the method that has [Authorize] keywork via POSTMAN, I am getting a 401 Unauthorized as a response.  Can someone help me with this?  Here are the relevant codes in the implementation.

```
    *********** API ENDPOINT ***********
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
    {
      if (_context.Users == null)
      {
          return NotFound();
      }
        return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
    }
```

---

```
    *********** Program.cs ***********
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;    
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });

    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseCors();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
```

---

```
    *********** GENERATES THE TOKEN ***********
    private string GetToken()
    {
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),                
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, "1516239022"),
            new Claim("userId" , "1"),
            new Claim("name", "Jason"),
            new Claim("userName", "Jason"),
            new Claim("email", "jason@gmail.com")
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("lectureTest12345"));
        var singIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _configuration["Jwt: Issuer"],
                _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                signingCredentials: singIn
                );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core 6 JWT token has invalid signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056064/net-core-6-jwt-token-has-invalid-signature)

Answer (score 0):

> But when I tried to call the method that has [Authorize] keywork via
> POSTMAN, I am getting a 401 Unauthorized as a response.

I have answer you at your last post question, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056064/net-core-6-jwt-token-has-invalid-signature) .

Comment: I tried your soln and its not working

Comment: I am not getting a verified signature, but the issue now is using the generated JWT token in postman. Postman is kept on sending a 401 response.

Comment: @user19927732 ,  It's strange I use your code and make these changes and it works, Could you build a small demo and share it via gihub  ?