# Invalid Signature JWT in .Net Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-7.0

I always get invalid signature when I input the generated token in jwt.io Here is my code for making the token:

```
private string GenerateJwtToken(string userID, string username, string issuer, string audience, string secretkey)
        {
            // Set the token expiration time
            DateTime expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["AppSettings:JWT_EXP_TIME"])!);
       
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, expiration.ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userID),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, username),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),

            };
            
            SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretkey));
            SigningCredentials credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            
                JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer,
                audience,
                claims,
                signingCredentials: credentials
                );
            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
```

I copy and paste the secret key in jwt.io as well.
I don't have any clue what I am doing wrong!!!

Comment: *I always get invalid signature when I input the generated token in jwt.io* - you most probaly did not paste your `secretkey` to the input field in the right column under *VERIFY SIGNATURE*. Without knowing the key, the signature can't be verified.

Comment: I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862105/jwt-io-says-signature-verified-even-when-key-is-not-provided/69862239#69862239) that shows the correct way of verifying a token on jwt.io.

Comment: @jps I exactly did as your instruction. still get Invalid Sig.

Comment: Then please show your token and secret (I expect it to be test data, so no security problem)

Comment: @jps token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1laWRlbnRpZmllciI6InRlc3RAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoiMS8yMi8yMDI0IDExOjQ2OjI34oCvQU0iLCJzdWIiOiJhY2E5YTQ4OS1mYWZmLTQ0MTgtODRjMC0zNjA3NDlmYmZiYzkiLCJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InRlc3RAZ21haWwuY29tIiwianRpIjoiMTY4Yzg4YjYtOGFiNy00ZDkwLWJjZTItM2Q4ZmY3NjhjNjlhIiwiaWF0IjoiMS8yMi8yMDI0IDEwOjQ2OjI34oCvQU0iLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo3MTIyIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwIn0.oEzJAaba0eqbTnWtX233wOvavsKnvWPZBmzRbXAD5rw     
////secret: $w@N0x@pPA^tH20244202hT^app@X0n@W$

Comment: I also can't verify the token with the given secret, but there isn't that much that can go wrong in the code. Check if you copied everything correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was in program.cs I had addIdentity() after JWT service. It should be before jwt service.

additionally I had to set my claims like this:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, issuer),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, EpochTime.GetIntDate(nowUtc).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, EpochTime.GetIntDate(expirationUtc).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, issuer),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud, audience)
                };
```