# How to properly get a HMACSHA256 hash through bash scripting

Tags: bash, jwt, base64, hmac, jwt.io

I'm in the process of trying to create a JWT token using my terminal/bash scripting. I currently have

```
header='{"typ": "JWT", "alg": "HS256"}'
payload= '{"iss": "'"dummy_key"'"}'
encoded_header=$(printf "$header" | openssl base64 -e -A | tr -d '=')
encoded_payload=$(printf "$payload" | openssl base64 -e -A | tr -d '=')

data=$encoded_header.$encoded_payload
signature=$(printf '%s' "$data" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac dummy_secret -binary | openssl base64 -e -A | tr -d '=')
```

in which data would print a valid header and payload, connected by a `.` (These values are just stored in variables earlier in the script. Header & Payload are fine).

When I paste the output of the full JWT token (Which is just `$data.$signature`) **example output:**

> eyJ0eXAiOiAiSldUIiwgImFsZyI6ICJIUzI1NiJ9Cg.eyJleHAiOiAxNzI0MDczMzI1LCAiaXNzIjogImR1bW15X2tleSJ9Cg./LI0Qs6U1p8x1zRFCwUe2kHW224L9js3fVW3UjpxO70

into https://jwt.io/ I get the below error for an `Invalid Signature`:

> Warning: Looks like your JWT signature is not encoded correctly using base64url (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rcfc4648#section-5). Note that the padding ("=" must be omitted as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rcfc4648#section-2

I have looked at some of the OpenSSL documentation and thought I was doing it correctly, however, this error is making me think otherwise. Does anyone know the proper bash scripting command in order to create a valid signature for this JWT header & payload?

Comment: Yeah I actually got it to work just removing the -n from the payload/header section. Even with printf it's the same invalid signature part. I have changed it to printf now though :)

Comment: Removing `-n` would not have given you the correct encoded output since the string being encoded would undesirably have included the `\n` that `echo` would add. If you're using `printf` in your code then show `printf` in your question, not `echo -n` which would spark a whole new round of the same discussion as we had yesterday but with other people.

Comment: I got a warning to delete it because it was apparently a duplicate question.

Comment: I guess my main question now coming from answers I have seen, can you get a valid signature from jwt.io from just pasting in a JWT token into the encoded section?

Comment: You should include in your question the values stored in `encoded_header` and `encoded_payload` so we have a [mcve] to test with, see [ask]. As written we don't know what string you're encoding which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: okay i have updated the question to include the values being used, hopefully that's enough?

Comment: In `payload= '{"iss": "'"dummy_key"'"}'` - a) you can't have a space after the `=`, and b) the `'`s in the middle of the string are actually ending and restarting the string and so are useless in this context and if you remove them you can also remove some of the `"`s too.

Comment: `printf "$header"` is very different from `printf '%s' "$header"` as I had recommended and you used for printing `$data`, With `printf "$var"` you're using `$var` as the **format** string for `printf`, not the string you want printed as-is, and so it'll fail for various contents of `$var`. Always do `printf '%s' "$var"` if you want a variable printed as-is without a terminating newline, not `printf "%var"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a warning:

> Warning: Looks like your JWT signature is not encoded correctly using base64url (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rcfc4648#section-5). Note that the padding ("=" must be omitted as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rcfc4648#section-2

that your token is not encoded correctly. A JWT needs to be Base64Url encoded, but you just created a token that is Base64 encoded and removed the padding. You also need to substitute `+` with `-` and `/` with `_` for proper Base64Url encoding.

```
signature=$(printf '%s' "$data" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac dummy_secret -binary | openssl base64 -e -A | sed 's/+/-/g; s:/:_:g; s/=\+$//')
```

The second very common problem is that many people forget to provide the secret or key that is needed to verify the signature on jwt.io. Without knowing the secret it's not possible to verify the signature.
The secret needs to be pasted into the input field in the right column of the JWT debugger under "VERIFY SIGNATURE" (replace the place holder *your-256-bit-secret*). And make sure to [do it in the right order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862105/jwt-io-says-signature-verified-even-when-key-is-not-provided) to avoid falsely verified tokens.

Comment: I am using the JWT plugin with Kong. The JWT credentials use a `key` and a `secret` which for testing purposes, I am using as `dummy_key` and `dummy_secret` as the values for both of these.

In the signature I just hardcoded dummy_secret but it should be aligned with the dummy_key which exists in the payload. If you paste that token in that I linked in the main post, you will see the payload of the "iss:" "dummy_key"

So what you're saying is though that the signature cannot be validated from just pasting the encoded JWT token into jwt.io?

Comment: @N.Blore the content of the `iss`-claim is sometimes used to get an URL for a JWK (JSON Web Key) with a public key when the token is signed with an asymmetric key.  But here in your case, you need to paste the secret in the field under "VERIFY SIGNATURE" in the right column.

Comment: Yep I see that part, but let's say I'm authenticating a request to a certain API Endpoint. Will this JWT token be able to do that? Just not fully understanding what the invalid signature means.

Invalid signature when pasting the jwt token into jwt.io and being presented with that error message is making me a bit confused as to whether this would work or not

Comment: If I type any character into the verify-signature section, it instantly validates the signature lol. That is also confusing me a bit

Comment: *...it instantly validates the signature* - I explained that behaviour in detail in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862105/jwt-io-says-signature-verified-even-when-key-is-not-provided

Comment: *Invalid Signature* on jwt.io does not necessarily mean that the signature is wrong, but just that it could not be verified. It was created using a certain secret and the validity can only be checked if jwt.io knows that secret.

Comment: that answer you gave on the other question is amazing, my signature works with the correct secret, and fails with the incorrect one. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @N.Blore thanks for the positive feedback

Comment: Just a follow up question on this actually, if trying to connect to something which requires this jwt token. I would use "curl http://localhost:8001/<route-path>
  -H 'Authorization: <jwt token>'. 

How do I pass in the secret through this request? It'll be invalid without it right?

Comment: The exact call depends on the API of the receiver, it might be  `-H 'Authorization: <jwt token>` or more commonly ` -H 'Authorization: Bearer <jwt token>`, but there are other variants possible. Regarding the secret: you usually don't pass a secret to the receiver.  Either you got the secret from the party that receives the token, so they know it, or the token issuer and consumer are the same party.

Comment: sorry, but got a "page not found (404)" on your link.

Comment: sorry i meant to link this documentation, copy paste fail https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/jwt/#send-a-request-with-the-jwt - question was basically if i need to do anything other than use this auth bearer and the token

Answer (score 1):

As per the RFC documentation, the signature also should be encoded using base64. Since the signature starts with a slash icon, it appears to be not a valid base64 encoded.

Below is a complete example of generating a JWT using an symmetric key. You can test the signature validation also. :)
I included the iat time also.

```
# Test the script by changing the secret and running the script
# secret='your-secret'
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the header
header='{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}'

# Get the current timestamp for the iat claim
current_timestamp=$(date +%s)

# Define the payload with the dynamic iat
payload="{\"sub\":\"1234567890\",\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"iat\":$current_timestamp}"

# Base64 URL encode the header and payload
base64UrlEncode() {
    echo -n "$1" | openssl enc -base64 -A | sed 's/=*$//' | sed 's/\+/-/g' | sed 's/\//_/g'
}

encodedHeader=$(base64UrlEncode "$header")
encodedPayload=$(base64UrlEncode "$payload")

# Create the signature
secret='your-secret-key'
signature=$(echo -n "$encodedHeader.$encodedPayload" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$secret" -binary | openssl enc -base64 -A | sed 's/=*$//' | sed 's/\+/-/g' | sed 's/\//_/g')

# Concatenate the header, payload, and signature to form the JWT
jwt="$encodedHeader.$encodedPayload.$signature"

echo "JWT: $jwt"

# Validate the JWT-----------------------

# Test the script by changing the secret and running the script
# secret='your-secret'


# Split the JWT into its three parts
header=$(echo -n $jwt | cut -d "." -f1)
payload=$(echo -n $jwt | cut -d "." -f2)
signature=$(echo -n $jwt | cut -d "." -f3)

# Base64 URL decode the header and payload
base64UrlDecode() {
    local padded=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/-/\+/g' | sed 's/_/\//g' | awk '{printf "%s", $0; for (i=0; i<(4-length($0)%4)%4; i++) printf "="}')
    echo -n "$padded" | openssl enc -base64 -d -A
}

decodedHeader=$(base64UrlDecode "$header")
decodedPayload=$(base64UrlDecode "$payload")

# Verify the signature
verifySignature=$(echo -n "$header.$payload" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$secret" -binary | openssl enc -base64 -A | sed 's/=*$//' | sed 's/\+/-/g' | sed 's/\//_/g')

echo "Decoded header: $decodedHeader"
echo "Decoded payload: $decodedPayload"
echo "Signature: $signature"
echo "Verify signature: $verifySignature"


if [ "$verifySignature" == "$signature" ]; then
    echo "Signature is valid"
else
    echo "Signature is invalid"
fi
```

Comment: YMMV using `echo -n "$data"`, see [why-is-printf-better-than-echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819).