'Invalid Signature' on JTW>io debugger
I'm trying to implement JWT token generation & verification in a .net core 7 API solution.
Getting an 'Invalid Signature' when I tried to view the details of a token on JWT.io.
Tried solutions:

Using Base64 encoded key as secret.
Checking/Un-checking 'secret base64 encoded' checkbox
Converting jwt secret to base64 in Appsettings.json file.

Can anyone throw some light on my mistake??
Thanks in advance :)
The issue

Code snapshots
private string CreateJWTToken(User user)
        {

            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>{
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)
                // new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"AssignSomeRole"),
            };

            var SymmetricKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("JWT:secret").Value!));

            var SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(SymmetricKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

            var JwtTokenForUser = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "http://localhost:5255",
                audience: "",
                claims: claims,
                null,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                signingCredentials: SigningCredentials
            );

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(JwtTokenForUser);

            return jwt;
        }

In Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                builder.Configuration.GetSection("JWT:secret").Value!))
    };
});

AppSetting.json as follows:
  "JWT": {
    "secret": "trytrytrytrytrytrytrytrytrytrytrytrytrytrytrytry",
    "issuer": "http://localhost:5255",
    "audience": "http://localhost:5255"
  }


Can you pls. share the token so that I can try? If the secret is correct and you did it in the right order (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862105/jwt-io-says-signature-verified-even-when-key-is-not-provided/69862239#69862239) it should work. Clicking on "Secret Base64 encoded"  when the secret is not encoded leads to wrong results.

@jps Thanks for considering. It turned out that a know issue is there with hmacsha256signature algorithm. Although it is supported by. Net core
